# JQuery UI Dialog: Password inputs causing freezing

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, yii, jquery-ui-dialog

This is a odd behavior that seems to only happen in Chrome and with JQuery UI.  When entering characters into a password field at first everything functions correctly.  However, if you attempt to backspace to the last letter in the input, the browser locks up all client side operations.  Also, if you try and highlight the characters entered and backspace the client side operations freeze.

Just reaching out to see if anyone has encountered this same issue, and how they resolved it.

In order to experience the issue, we have the dialog auto opening on 2+ unique page home views.  Here is a listings page so it can be triggered, I apologize for the inconvenience but I can't remove the counter.

Page: http://www.christineleeteam.com/area/eagleharbor

Comment: Could you link us to a site where it behaves as you described?

Comment: Do you have a JSfiddle or something were you can show the issue?

Comment: Updated the original post with the example, thanks!

Comment: Hmm, works completely fine here in my Chrome (latest public version).

Comment: I cleared out my cache, cookies, etc... and that seems to have resolved it.  I wonder if Chrome has a event handler for when the password field updates?

Comment: I found the same issue on chrome browser with input type password and jQuery chosen plugin. Note, our project does not use jQuery UI -  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15895951/ui-freezes-in-some-browsers-while-deleting-last-char-of-password-field-in-presen

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem but cache clearing didn't help. I'm sure it isn't a jquery ui bug.
Here is my solution:

```
   $('input[type="password"]').on('keydown', function(event){
     if (event.which == 8) { //backspace event
       event.preventDefault();
       $(this).val('');
     }
   });
```

This code is clearing the whole password field on one backspace event.

Comment: Great answer to a difficult problem which was driving me insane.

Answer (score 4):

We encountered the same issue, and used Benkod's solution.
We improved it a little to also handle cases where the password text is deleted with the delete key (and not backspace).
Another case is when all the text in the control is selected and new text is typed to replace it.
Here is the script we used:

```
    Sys.Application.add_load(function() {
        $('input[type=password]').keydown(function(event) {

            var isAllTextSelected = this.value.slice(this.selectionStart, this.selectionEnd) == this.value;
            var isLastChar = $(this).val().length == 1;
            if (isAllTextSelected && $(this).val().length > 0) {
                $(this).val('');
            }
            if ((event.which == 8 || event.which == 46) && (isLastChar || isAllTextSelected)) { //backspace event

                event.preventDefault();
                $(this).val('');
            }
        });
    });
```

Comment: Great addition to the initial solution.  I tried looking into the cause of this issue but just don't have the time to hassle with it anymore so thanks a ton.

Answer (score 0):

Same problem here (FWIW, I'm using Twitter Bootstrap, but the issue was the same). [It looks like](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=121918) it's caused by having a lot of content preceding the input. Placing the input higher--above the bulk of other content--did the trick for me. A work around, but better than nothing.