# UI freezes in some browsers while deleting last char of password field in presence of jquery chosen

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, jquery-chosen

I am using jQuery **chosen** plugin in my project and this issue is happening on trying to edit any `input type="password"` (deleting the last character in the password field), whenever there is `.chosen()` binded to any select dropdown on the same page. I could reproduce the issue on chrome browser (version 26.0.1410.43 m), although people have found the issue on Firefox and other browsers too. This happens any page having chosen applied to a dropdown. The issue seems to affect `input type="password"` fields only. Changing the type to `text` fixes the UI freeze issue.

So, what could be the main reason behind the issue? I found a similar issue, where jQuery UI is being used -

[JQuery UI Dialog: Password inputs causing freezing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14914361/jquery-ui-dialog-password-inputs-causing-freezing)

So, what approach did you guys follow. There is a work-around in an answer in the above mentioned link which works, but I was looking for a better solution.

Comment: I am having the same issue.  I took some time looking into the cause but have not discovered it yet.  I hope to get more time soon to continue investigating and if I figure it out I will try and find this post to update my progress.

Comment: I am having the same issue in my GWT application.  Speed Tracer shows that all of the time is being spent in the DOM Event for KeyDown.

Clearing the cache did not help, and as it's a dynamic GWT app, moving the code around is not an option.

Problem also triggered by Shift-A + Delete.